# How to make object serializable in unity c#

Tags: c#, object, unity-game-engine, serializable

At first it was a text but i want it to be an image/sprite, so i change it to object. But now i got these error. My errors are on line 50 and 51.

Pls help :(

> error: cannot apply indexing with to an expression of type object
>
> error: the left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable a property or
>   an indexer

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Kuis : MonoBehaviour {
    [SerializeField] Text teksPertanyaan;
    [SerializeField] Object[] teksPilihan;
    [SerializeField] Soal[] soal;
    [SerializeField] int indeksSoal;

//deklarasi lcm
int a, b, m, x, hasil;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    a = 4;
    b = 5;
    m = 9;
    x = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < soal.Length; i++) {
        x = (a * x + b) % m;
        hasil = x % 3;
        Debug.Log("" +hasil);
        tampilSoal (hasil);
    }
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}

IEnumerator dealay(){
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (1);
    //tampilSoal (Random.Range (1, 5));
    tampilSoal (Random.Range (0, soal.Length));
    //Debug.Log("" +hasil);
    Debug.Log("" +indeksSoal);
}

public void konten(){
    StartCoroutine (dealay ());
}

void tampilSoal(int _indeksSoal){
    indeksSoal = _indeksSoal;
    teksPertanyaan.text = soal [_indeksSoal].pertanyaan;
    for (int i = 0; i < soal [_indeksSoal].pilihan.Length; i++) {
        teksPilihan [i].ToString = soal [_indeksSoal].pilihan [i];
    }
}

public void verifikasiJawaban(int _indeksJawaban){
    if (_indeksJawaban == soal [indeksSoal].indeksJawaban) {
        print ("Jawaban Benar!");
        konten ();
    }
    else {
        //hilangSoal.SetActive (false);
        print ("Jawaban Salah!");
        konten ();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: teksPilihan [i].ToString makes no sense to me. First of all, if you want the String representation you need to invoke the method correctly - teksPilihan [i].ToString() with the parenthesis. But Strings are immutable in C# so I'm not sure what you're hoping to achieve. Perhaps you want to cast the incoming data as string? If so, the casting should be done on the other side of the equation.

Comment: regarding the first error: if the type of `Soal.pilihan` does not implement an [indexer property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/) in its class, you cannot do such a thing as `soal [_indeksSoal].pilihan [i]`. But it seems that it is an array, so it probably does.

Comment: `teksPilihan [i].ToString = soal [_indeksSoal].pilihan [i];` what are you trying to achieve with that, at all?